# SimpleCursorAdapter handling empty cursor

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I'm using a custom SimpleCursorAdapter. Currently my list stays empty, if no entries can be found in the database/cursor. Now, I want to display a message within the list, if there are no entries within the cursor/database. How can I handle this event?

Answer (score 6):

Just place the view you want displayed in your XML, and give it any id you like, eg:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- view to be shown/hidden on empty list above -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyListElem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nothing to show!" />
```

Then in your Activity's **onCreate()** method, call **setEmptyView()** on your listView object.  The ListView should handle showing/hiding your view object, depending on whether the list is empty or not.

```
    View empty = findViewById(R.id.emptyListElem);      
    listView.setEmptyView(empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

If your ListView is expressed in xml, you can add a TextView with a specific android:id which will automatically display your message if the list is empty, as below:

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:text="No Data exist"
           android:textSize="16dip"
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

You must use the @id/android:empty for this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentioned that: I know this possibility but my Activity is a normal `Activity` (no ListActivity) with a embedded `ListView`.